# CTServerConnectionGetCellID routine core telephony

Tags: iphone, ios, private, core-telephony

I want to retrive some cellular network informations such as cellId and LAC.
I know that there is no official way to do that, but i still experiencing some CoreTelephony routines such as CTServerConnectionGetCellID.

any luck to get this working ?

any help ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this [testing iPhone signal with code](http://blog.vladalexa.com/2010/07/07/iphone-signal-testing-with-code/)

It gives you CellID but I don't think it shows LAC, I could be misinterpreting some of the output though.

Comment: When I test the code from above link, Cell ID is appearing always as 0. Is there any other way to get it?

Comment: Hi, I had similar experience as well, my code shows LAC on 3G but not on 4G mode. My manager told me is not rare that on 4G it shows 0 as the LAC, and since we are working in a telecommunication company, I think his words are creditable.