# How to dump iOS 6 private api of CoreTelephony Framework?

Tags: ios, api, private

In the creker's post [Get CellID, MCC, MNC, LAC, and Network in iOS 5.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13399659/get-cellid-mcc-mnc-lac-and-network-in-ios-5-1/19400475#19400475), he mentioned that there are some private api in CoreTelephony Framework, such as **_CTServerConnectionCreate**.

I've tried the "class-dump" tool but it didn't work. eg: Using 'class-dump -H CoreTelephony -o Headers ' i didn't see any function name has 'CTServer' prefix in dump file. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal -> use command "cd" move to class_dump directory. 
create "data" directory
and use terminal command   :

./class-dump -o ./data -H /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony

-> get result in "data" directory.

Comment: Your method is just the same as mine, and i get the dump files contain some header files such as "CTCall.h" but not containing 'CTServer' prefix function, why? Did I miss something.