# Starting app on text message receive using theos tweak

Tags: ios, iphone, jailbreak, cydia, theos

I'm trying to start an app if I receive an text message from an special sender.
Currently my Tweak.xm looks like this:

```
#import <SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <ChatKit/ChatKit.h>
#import <ChatKit/CKSMSMessage.h>
#import <ChatKit/CKSMSEntity.h>
#import <ChatKit/CKSMSService.h>
#import <ChatKit/CKConversation.h>

#import <CoreTelephony/CoreTelephony.h>

%hook SMSCTServer
- (void)_ingestIncomingCTMessage:(CTMessage *)arg1
{
  %orig;
  UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Welcome"
        message:@"Received :D!"
        delegate:nil
        cancelButtonTitle:@";)"
        otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
%end
%hook SpringBoard

-(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(id)application {
    %orig;

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Welcome"
        message:@"Test!"
        delegate:nil
        cancelButtonTitle:@"Test"
        otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}

%end

%hook CKSMSService

-(void)_receivedMessage:(CKSMSRecordRef)message replace:(BOOL)replace{

    NSLog(@"received message  %@", message);
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Welcome"
        message:@"Welcome to your iPhone Brandon!"
        delegate:nil
        cancelButtonTitle:@"Thanks"
        otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];

        %orig;
}

%end
```

and this is the makefile:

```
include theos/makefiles/common.mk

TWEAK_NAME = Mytweak
Mytweak_FILES = Tweak.xm
Mytweak_FRAMEWORKS = ChatKit Foundation CoreGraphics UIKit AudioToolbox
Mytweak_PRIVATE_FRAMEWORKS = CoreTelephony
include $(THEOS_MAKE_PATH)/tweak.mk

after-install::
        install.exec "killall -9 SpringBoard"
```

But I don´t know how to install the Coretelephonyframework, I always get the error:

```
Tweak.xm:8:9: fatal error: 'CoreTelephony/CoreTelephony.h' file not found
import <CoreTelephony/CoreTelephony.h>
```

Does anyone know how to install the framework into theos? I am completely new to jailbreakapp coding.

Comment: what version of iOS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20417919/754604) shows how to use class dump to get the private headers for CoreTelephony. Once you have the headers put them in the include directory for theos. I think `/var/theos/include` is the default. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

CoreTelephony.h is unnecessary for your tweak