# Base Station Identifying Code (BSIC) iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, cdma

Is it possible to get the Base Station Identifying Code (BSIC) programmatically? It doesn´t matter if Apple would reject The Application. I just want to know weather it is possible or not! I already looked into the Core-telephony Framework, but I could´t find something. Maybe there are private Api´s? The Base is iOS 7.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get CellID, MCC, MNC, LAC, and Network in iOS 5.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13399659/get-cellid-mcc-mnc-lac-and-network-in-ios-5-1)

Comment: It is not a duplicate because i am talking about the Base Station ID, not the Cell ID...

Comment: What do you mean by Base Station ID?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_station_identity_code

Comment: There is no BSIC in CoreTelephony, at least it's not mentioned in any exported symbols. What you can get for GSM are CID, LAC, MCC, MNC, ARFCN. It more that enough to uniquely identify BS.