# Get CellID,LAC,PCI,RSRP,RSRQ,SINR From iPhone 5s Qualcomm MDM9615M Baseband Chip

Tags: ios, iphone, cellid, lte

How can I Get CellID,LAC,PCI,RSRP,RSRQ,SINR From iPhone 5s Qualcomm MDM9615M Baseband Chip?

I need more details from Qualcomm MDM9615M Baseband Chip.
Such as:
MCC, MNC, SectorLat, SectorLong, CellId, LAC, UARFCN, RxLev, TimingAdvance, BandInfo, ARFCN,
RSSI, PSC, RSCP, ECN0, SCN, PCI, TAC, PID, RSRP, RSRQ, SNR, Bandwidth, BandClass, ChannelNumber,
PNOffset, ChangeMask, DerivedMCC, Ecio, EcioFiltered, RxAGC, RefPn, NgbrPn, RefEcio, SID, NID
BaseStationId, BaseStationLat, BaseStationLong, ZoneId, LtmOffset, DayLightSaving, SectorId

I found Field Test source code for iPhone4 but not available
 on iPhone5s:
http://www.61ic.com/code/attachment.php?aid=81527&k=e18ef882fe7ba27842765eaf014c0f9a&t=1395988757

Here is how to access to iPhone4 Baseband using Minicom:
http://www.letsunlockiphone.com/hacking-iphone-5-qualcomm-baseband/

Comment: Can you tell us what you have tried and supply some more details?

Answer (score 3):

I was also looking for this stuff.
i found here the answer: [Get CellID, MCC, MNC, LAC, and Network in iOS 5.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13399659/get-cellid-mcc-mnc-lac-and-network-in-ios-5-1)
It seems to work for ios 7 as well (even they ask for ios5).

however - it uses private api's which means you can't load it to apple store.