# Get 2G and 3G Network details with CellID in iPhone SDK

Tags: ios, iphone, core-telephony, cellid, lcid

I need to get CellID,LAC etc using iPhone SDK.

I have used CoreTelephony as mentioned in this given link :
[Get CellID, MCC, MNC, LAC, and Network in iOS 5.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13399659/get-cellid-mcc-mnc-lac-and-network-in-ios-5-1)

But i am getting the cell count of 0 and unable to get the CellID,LAC. I am getting MCC and MNC as mentioned in above link.

I need CellID and LAC of the current Network Cell to which my iPhone is connected. Please help