# How to get CellInfo, SNR, UARFCN, BandWidth... on iOS9.x

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone-privateapi, cellular-network, core-telephony

I want radio information with CoreTelephony.framework on iOS 9.x.
And I tried the following this question.
[Get CellID, LAC, ... on iOS 8.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29533059/get-cellid-lac-on-ios-8-3)

Add this xml on plist,

```
    <key>com.apple.CommCenter.fine-grained</key>
<array>
    <string>spi</string>
</array>
```

But not working this code.

```
_CTServerConnectionCopyWakeReason
_CTServerConnectionCopyVoiceMailInfo
```

with this code.

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] platformString] isEqual: @"iPhone 6"]) {
    void (*_CTServerConnectionCopyWakeReason)(struct CTServerConnection*, void*, CFArrayRef*) = dlsym(handle, "_CTServerConnectionCopyWakeReason");
    _CTServerConnectionCopyWakeReason(_conn, &tmp, &cells);
} else {
    void (* _CTServerConnectionCopyWakeReason)(struct CTResult*, struct CTServerConnection*, void*, CFArrayRef*) = dlsym(handle, "_CTServerConnectionCopyWakeReason");
    _CTServerConnectionCopyWakeReason(&res, _conn, &tmp, &cells);
}
```

If you know how get iOS radio information, it is no problem if any private APIs.

Comment: My answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13399659/get-cellid-mcc-mnc-lac-and-network-in-ios-5-1 has all the answers  It's not possible any more, you need jailbreak

Comment: Only I just use a private API perform the jailbreak iPhone?

Comment: I have jailbreak iPhone and use it, but can't get cellinfo, snr, uarfcn and any radio information.