# Get signal strength on phone running iOS 8.3

Tags: ios, iphone, core-telephony, ios8.3

An app of mine uses `CTGetSignalStrength()` to get the iPhone's signal strength. However, it turns out that in iOS 8.3 this private API call just returns 0. I read that getting the signal strength [is no longer possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29795817/get-cellid-mcc-mnc-lac-signal-strength-quality-and-network-in-ios-8-3).

Is there a way that I can get the dBm signal strength from the iPhone programmatically on iOS 8.3?