# Signal strength in ios 8.3

Tags: ios, ios8.3, core-telephony, signal-strength

Apple has restricted API to fetch signal strength but there is a way to get this i found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29795817/get-cellid-mcc-mnc-lac-signal-strength-quality-and-network-in-ios-8-3).Is it a correct way to get signal strength. I am developing for iTunes store submission. Will apple reject my app? Solution provided by @Mateusz Mirkowski as follow :

```
UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
NSArray *subviews = [[[app valueForKey:@"statusBar"]     valueForKey:@"foregroundView"] subviews];
NSString *dataNetworkItemView = nil;


     for (id subview in subviews) {
   if([subview isKindOfClass:[NSClassFromString(@"UIStatusBarSignalStrengthItemView") class]])
   {
        dataNetworkItemView = subview;
        break;
    }
 }
int signalStrength = [[dataNetworkItemView valueForKey:@"signalStrengthRaw"] intValue];

NSLog(@"signal %d", signalStrength);
```

Comment: You are using private classes, which Apple does not allow this. Any method to detect the signal strength will have to use private classes, thus there is no way to do this and get approved for the AppStore.

Comment: is UIStatusBarSignalStrengthItemView private.?

Comment: Yep, it not in the public SDK.

Comment: Thanks for that @rckoenes

Comment: Where did you read that apple restricted the API to fetch signal strength?

Comment: @K_Mohit Did they approve your app to app store after adding the above lines of code to your app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using anything that Apple does not allow, it will certainly leads to the **App rejection**.