# In iOS 11 & above is it possible to get iPhone Signal Strength, Call Drop count, IMEI, MAC address using api or any workaround

Tags: ios11, phone-call, mac-address, imei, signal-strength

In iOS 11 or above I need to get these parameters by code using any API/workaround is also welcome :).
parameters are: signal strength, call drop count, IMEI, MAC address.

Is it possible to do so or not.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly not through public API, signal strength for cell signal was possible to get prior iOS11 (like pointed here [Signal strength in ios 8.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32202014/signal-strength-in-ios-8-3))