# Is there a complete Swift 4.0 code to get current MCC, MNC and LAC from the antenna like as in the FieldTest mode

Tags: ios, swift, core-telephony

I need to get access to the current MCC and MNC only on iOS 12 in Swift 4 from the actual antenna. I do NOT want the MCC and MNC of the SIM card provided by serviceSubscriberCellularProviders. I know this is some Private API stuff forbidden by Apple, but yet I still need it, the app isn't meant to be distributed through the App Store.

I did try to search the web for this, however I only found some weird Objective-C code that I cannot convert into Swift, and some C++ header file I don't quite understand...

I do not have any code as I am starting from scratch with this issue.

I expect from a "250 14" SIM card to show the MCC and MNC of the actual antenna, so for example "134 01" if the user is aboard.

Answer (score 0):

I can help you to convert objective-c to swift with the below link you can convert.
https://objectivec2swift.com/#/converter/code/

Try to Find MNC and MCC with the below link.
first, convert it to swift.
[Getting the MCC and MNC by means of CoreTelephony.framework private API in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30032743/getting-the-mcc-and-mnc-by-means-of-coretelephony-framework-private-api-in-objec/33206170)