# How can I get lac,cellID and all of these device information?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7, ios8

How can I get all this device information using private API? I'm not gonna release this app in app store. It's just for learning purpose. And for the iOS version I'm using iOS 7 & 8. Thank you in advance.

```
"lac": location area code,
"cellId": cell tower id,
"speed": speed in meter per second using accelerometer,
"direction": compass,
"current": current level,
"temp": device temperature,
"imei": imei,
"phoneNumber":phoneNumber::string.
```

Answer (score 0):

First, by definition, you can not use a private API on iOS, especially if you want to publish it on the store. Apple verify this.

But if you dare passe Apple verification for CellId and Lac, you can check this:

[Get CellID, MCC, MNC, LAC, and Network in iOS 5.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13399659/get-cellid-mcc-mnc-lac-and-network-in-ios-5-1)

Phonenumber is not know by the device, only network got it

direction, and speed : check Apple api for this

Comment: thank you. How can I use that solution code @tomsoft? Sorry, I'm novice. :)

Comment: about this artile，Get CellID, MCC, MNC, LAC, and Network in iOS 5.1，it is workable. but it is not work above ios 8.3 except you jarlbreak.
and also i can not get the cdma cell information.