# Universal solution to find CID and LAC

Tags: android, ios, windows-phone, gsm, cellid

I'm looking for any universal cross-platform (Android/iOS/WinPhone) solution to find CID (Cell Identifier) and LAC (Location area code). Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no cross platform solution.  This is code you need to implement separately for each platform.

LAC and CellId come directly from the device, so it makes sense that you need to get them from device-specific interfaces.

The phones all use the same protocols to get LAC and Cell Id from the mobile network, but app developers have no direct access to the mobile network, so we must get the information via the mobile phone.

You're stuck with individual solutions for [Android](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/gsm/GsmCellLocation.html), [iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13399659/get-cellid-mcc-mnc-lac-and-network-in-ios-5-1) and [Windows Phone](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1b17d1ca-e50c-4492-a179-23789a77fba3/retrieving-cell-id-mnc-mcc-lac-imei-imsi-in-windows-mobile?forum=vssmartdevicesvbcs).