# Get CellID and LAC programatically in iOS 10.x

Tags: ios, ios10

I am trying to get CellID and LAC programmatically in iOS 10.x.

I tried [Get CellID, MCC, MNC, LAC, and Network in iOS 5.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13399659/get-cellid-mcc-mnc-lac-and-network-in-ios-5-1) but this is not working in 8.3 and above versions.

Can anyone help me to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

```
//mcc
CTTelephonyNetworkInfo *netInfo = [[CTTelephonyNetworkInfo alloc] init];
CTCarrier *carrier = [netInfo subscriberCellularProvider];
NSString *mcc = [carrier mobileCountryCode];

//mnc
NSString *mnc = [carrier mobileNetworkCode];
NSLog(@"mcc: %@, mnc: %@", mcc, mnc);
```

Comment: There are not CellID and LAC!